# How to change drop-down background color on QComboBox hover

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qcombobox

I need to change the drop-down button background of the QComboBox when the mouse hover on QComboBox.

If I write:

```css
QComboBox::drop-down:hover
```

It would be wrong because it is a selector to hover over the drop-down button, not over the QComboBox.

I mean this button:

[image]

[Qt Style Sheets Reference — `::drop-down` subcontrol](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-reference.html#drop-down-sub)

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [QComboBox Styling](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcombobox).

If I'm not mistaken, you should implement your own method: `void QComboBox::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)`, when the **mouse hovers the combobox, we change its stylesheet**:

```css
QComboBox{
    ...
    backround:red;
    ...
}
```

And after, when the mouse gets out of our combobox, we reset the stylesheet to the default:

```css
QComboBox{
}
```